# Scale height of div when width of device is for mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am building a site that uses a very large header image. When the site is viewed on mobile I would like to scale that header div's height to be half of what is is on desktop.

What is the best way to do this with `bootstrap 3`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple media query will work:

```
@media all and (max-width: 480px) { // or whatever size you want to target
    // change header size
}
```

Comment: Yeah, duh. Not sure what I was thinking.